# SVG pattern with viewBox display differently in Safari and Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, svg, browser, safari, viewbox

Following svg segment defines a graph with major/minor lines. It behaves as expected in Chrome. But the ending minor line mis-aligned with major line for each square. Any idea why?

```
<svg width="8in" height="11in" viewBox="0 0 960 1320">
    <defs>
        <pattern id="smallGrid" width="12" height="12" patternUnits="userSpaceOnUse">
            <path d="M 12 0 L 0 0 0 12" fill="none" stroke="gray" stroke-width="0.5"></path>
        </pattern>
        <pattern id="grid12" width="120" height="120" patternUnits="userSpaceOnUse">
            <rect width="120" height="120" fill="url(#smallGrid)"></rect>
            <path d="M 120 0 L 0 0 0 120" fill="none" stroke="blue" stroke-width="1"></path>
        </pattern>
    </defs>
    <rect fill="white" height="800" width="800" y="0"></rect>
    <rect fill="url(#grid12)" height="360" width="360" y="0"></rect>
</svg>
```